# The Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A$ and $B$ be complex matrices of sizes $3\times5$ and $5\times3$ respectively, with
>   $AB=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & -1
> \end{bmatrix}
> $.
>
> Find a Jordan form of $BA$.

Comment: What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: I am just thinking about how we can obtain BA from AB

Comment: Think to the nonzero eigenvalues of $BA$.

Comment: How can i find them ...cause I don't know the matrix

Comment: $AB$ and $BA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Super .then I can deal with it I think ...thanks a lot

Comment: How can i complete it ?